# Data after installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: files, 15.10, data-loss

I am interested in installing the new version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 15.10. Is there any way to do so without deleting my files and previously installed programmes?

Answer (score 0):

1. backup your personal data. Always important to do anyways. Store what is important on an USB. I do not bother with video and music (I could always re-download those but my projects are on my system, on a backup on an external medium and stored on-line at an ftp I own).
2. do not format the location you stored them. You can do that using the "something else" method or picking the "replace but save my documents" method.

   Tip: I have my data on a separate partition and not in /home/ and edited  `~./config/user-dirs.dirs` to point to that partition. So I format / and /home, mount them and mount my partition without format without any risk of loosing personal file. My /home/ is empty except for the hidden files.